# How to find the starting position of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Simple question, but hard to find the answer! How can i get the coordinates of my UIImageView?

I would like to print those coordinates with NSLog, and i tried this:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(elefant.frame));
```

I would like to be able to place a drag able image in its start position when the touch end.

Hope to find help here, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to print the frame of your `UIImageView` and the coordinate for `X` or `Y` position. *(You can get min, max or mid X/Y)*.

```
NSLog(@"width : %f - height : %f - x : %f - y : %f", CGRectGetWidth(elefant.frame), CGRectGetHeight(elefant.frame), CGRectGetMinX(elefant.frame), CGRectGetMinY(elefant.frame));
```

Comment: I don't understand. Add some core and more explanation please.

Comment: Hi Jordan. You already told me the answer :) (mid X/Y). Thank you so much. If you know how to make an animation on this: elefant.center = CGPointMake(359, 151); I will be glad :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to valid the answer ;)
What kind of animation do you want ?

Comment: I want an moving animation from (a to b) where i can change the speed.

Comment: You can use an animation. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907898/iphone-view-move-animation