# Animating UIview from top to bottom and vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIView` at X=0 and Y=0 location with the height of 110 and `UIButton` at the bottom of the screen with the height of 50, i want to show both by animating but the `UIView` must animate from top to to its height and `UIButton` from bottom to its height, i am totally new with this please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

basic animation which may fit your requirement

```
[UIView transitionWithView:view
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                animations:^{
                   //update your frame here;
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Please go thru [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907898/iphone-view-move-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me to show a search view on top.

```
if (!isSearchActive) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         searchView.frame   =   CGRectMake(0, 56, mainWidth, 50);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
    isSearchActive=YES;
}
else{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         searchView.frame   =   CGRectMake(0, 56, mainWidth, 0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
    isSearchActive=NO;
}
```

Call this code on click of any button to show and hide the view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for top to bottom Animation:

```
- (CAAnimation*)movedown;
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    animation.keyPath = @"position.y";
    animation.fromValue = @600;
    animation.toValue = @50;
    animation.duration = 0.25;

    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];


    [trashView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
    trashView.layer.position =CGPointMake(0,-20);
    return animation;
}
```

and Code for Bottom to Top:

```
- (CAAnimation*)moveup;
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    animation.keyPath = @"position.y";
    animation.fromValue = @-500;
    animation.toValue = @10;
    animation.duration = 0.25;

    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];


    [trashView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
    trashView.layer.position =CGPointMake(0,20);
    return animation;

}
```

for first block of code you can use to animate view but you have to replace your `viewcontroller` at `trashview` in code.

and second block use for button but you have to replace your button at `trashview`.

but you can set value of animation according to your need.

Comment: i have tried this and it works well. just you have to change value and set animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private func startAnimation() {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
            animation.fromValue = 10  //Top Y 
            animation.toValue = 204  //Bottom Y
            animation.duration = 15 * 0.10 //duration * speed
            animation.repeatCount = 100
            animation.autoreverses = false
            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
            animation.fillMode = .forwards
            self.yourView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position.y")
        }

  private func stopAnimation() {
        self.yourView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
```